# How long before I get my new Canada TRV (temporary resident visa)?

Tags: visa, canada

CIC has received my TRV application on June 20. My flight is scheduled on July 29, from Toronto to Beijing. I am a recent student at the University of Waterloo, and I have just extended my study permit. I use the new study permit to apply for the TRV. However, my old TRV has already expired before the new application.

I have heard that some people say it usually takes 2-4 weeks to get a new TRV. Now, I have been waiting for a week. Does this 2-4 weeks time include the mailing time?

Do you think I should cancel my flight now? Or, it is safe for the current time?

Comment: No it doesn't include the processing time in mail. And CIC suggests you should never book tickets before you get a visa and they are not responsible if you miss your flight.

Comment: "Do you think I should cancel my flight now": StackExchange generally discourages opinions.  But since your visa should be ready in 1 to 3 weeks, and your flight is in 4.5 weeks, that leaves 1.5 weeks or more for the mailing time, which seems plenty.